Nuxt image using Nuxt booster not being able to set the correct image size I want
So I am trying to use Nuxt Image to optimize my images, but since I have nuxt-booster installed, so I use booster-image.
In my code I defined the booster-image and bind the properties:
<BoosterImage v-bind="{source, title, alt}" critical></BoosterImage>

And then in my script tag
defineProps({
  source: {
    type: Object,
    default() {
      return {
        format: 'webp',
        src: '/img/slider/slider-img-1.webp',
        sizes: {
          default: '100vw',
          xxs: '100vw',
          xs: '50vw',
          sm: '50vw',
          md: '100vw',
          lg: '100vw',
          xl: '100vw',
          xxl: '100vw''
        },
      }
    }
  },
  title: String,
  alt: String
});

But I have two problems, first one is the image get blurry on load and on my laptop size is really big, can't control the size, but on mobile screens it is smaller.

I want to be able to control the size of the image perfectly and also increase the sharpness on larger screens.
My second problem using this syntax
v-bind="{source, title, alt}"

Is that the images are not one, they're iterated and selected. So how can I pass this dynamic image value to the source?
Those are my two questions.
I used booster image to boost the loading of the image as I get poor results from it in my lighthouse tests so all suggestions are welcome.
